# Get variable inside Closure with complete?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Closure Function which creates a PDF File - that could take some time and there is a progress function included. My problem is, how can i receive that "progress" outside my closure?

For example:

```
func makeReport(fileName:String, task: Task, completion:@escaping (_ success:Bool) -> Void) {
    .....
    let _ = pdf.generatePDF(fileName, progress: {
        progress in
        print(progress) // here is my progress
    })

    completion(true) // returns when the file is created, so i know that i am now able to show the PDF
}
```

I call my function with:

```
pdfCreator.makeReport(fileName: filename, task: self.task, completion: {success in
   // any chance to get my progress to update a spinner for example?
   if success == true {
       // file is here
   }
}
```

Comment: Add a new parameter of another function to track the progress.

Comment: But is the completion not only returned when finished?

Comment: Yes, but you can pass multiple closures to your `makeReport` function; one to be called periodically with updated progress and one to be called when it is complete

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out.

Comment: But my problem here is that i need to get an variable from the inner closure function (the generatePDF is a closure too) - how can i call that function inside the inner closure function?

Comment: You could make a protocol (PdfCreatorDelegate) with a method (didUpdateProgress), and update your method to take a PdfCreatorDelegate as a parameter can call it in your closure as needed.

Comment: It also looks like your `completion` is being called immediately.

Comment: Ah ok, now it is working. Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example using a playground that should help you out:

```
func makeReport(fileName: String, progress: @escaping (_ progress: CGFloat) -> Void, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

  var progressOfTask: CGFloat = 0.0
  let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        progressOfTask += 10
        progress(progressOfTask)
        if progressOfTask == 100.0 {
            completion(true)
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
    timer.fire()
}


makeReport(fileName: "", progress: { progress in
    print(progress)
}, completion: { success in
    print(success)
})

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Output:

```
10.0
20.0
30.0
40.0
50.0
60.0
70.0
80.0
90.0
100.0
true
```

Comment: Thanks - now ill return both values with the completion handler (i always thought that handler will just be called on "completion" - and i am not able to get any values before) - but now it works (ill just return a success and a progress each time) - so check when success is true to find out when the pdf is created, and before i am able to grab the progress.